# Is there a way to start a docker container on an external attempt to connect to the root ip and port?

Tags: docker, server

I was wondering if there is a way to start a docker container, when its adress is pinged?
I am shutting down containers daily via a cronjob and want them to start with the first connection attempt on that day.

I googled for it and searched on stack overflow. But sadly I am relatively new to server and docker.

Comment: You can make a lightweight server, which listens to incoming requests, when received, initialize the container. But this initialization may take time and also, the server will have to be up all the time.
Or, you can use service like [Google cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy)

Comment: Any suggestions, which one to take? Or any resources on that topic?
Are you talking about Availability Group Listener?